# testing callbacks after_update rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have 2 models `User.rb` and `Client.rb`. Relationship is:

**User.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, inverse_of: :users
```

**Client**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, inverse_of: :clients
```

Callbacks in `User.rb` model

```
after_create :client_not_erasable
after_update :assign_client


def client_not_erasable
.
.
end

def assign_client
  def to_param
    return Client.find(client_to_add) unless client_to_add.nil?
  end
  unless client_to_add.nil?
    if to_param.users.count.zero? && client_to_add.present?
      to_param.update_attributes(erasable:false)
    end
  end
end
```

First callback `after_create :client_not_erasable` is working fine, but second callback `after_update :assign_client` doesn't work. I'm getting true. I should get **false**

## Hooks

```
describe 'after_save and after_update callbacks' do
  let(:user) { build(:user) }
  let(:client) { build(:client) }
  it 'erasable client field should be false after of an user create' do
    user.clients.count == 1
    user.clients[0].erasable = true
    user.run_callbacks :create
    expect(user.clients[0].erasable).to be(false)
  end
  it 'erasable client field should be false after of it is assigned to user' do
    client.erasable = true
    user.run_callbacks :update
    expect(client.erasable).to be(false)
  end
end
```

Testing result:

```
Failures:

  1) User Validations after_save and after_update erasable client field should be false after of it is assigned to user
     Failure/Error: expect(client.erasable).to be(false)

       expected false
            got true
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:93:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: OT: defining method in method (`def` inside `def`) is not the best idea... Also your callback are quite complex, it may be easier to introduce service objects to handle this logig

Comment: @sawa, I want to pass the test. @mrzasa if you know a better option to know `client_to_add` value from front-end, i'm accepting suggestions. I do not want touch controller to know `client_to_add` value, i need do it in User model. Thank you!

Comment: When using RSpec with boolean matchers: `expect(client).to_not be_erasable`

Comment: @tomatito What is `client_to_add`? You're not setting it anywhere, and you haven't shown where it's defined. Unless `build(:client)` sets the value (??), then of course this test will fail.

Comment: @tomatito Perhaps for example you're just missing the line: `user.client_to_add = client` in your spec??

Comment: In the failing spec the `client` and the `user` are not attached to one another. You are building a `client` and building a `user` but they are completely disassociated objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to yzalavin response. the code that is finally working fine is:

#### Hooks

```
context 'Hooks' do
  let(:client) { build(:client) }
  let(:user) { build(:user) }
  let!(:users) { create_list(:user, 2, clients: [client]) } 
  it 'erasable client field should be false after of an user create' do
    user.clients.count == 1
    user.clients[0].erasable = true
    user.run_callbacks :create
    expect(user.clients[0].erasable).to be(false)
  end
  it 'erasable client field should be false after of it is assigned to user' do
    client.erasable = true
    user.run_callbacks :update
    expect(client.reload.erasable).to be(false)
  end
end
```

Thank you